# PHP - What data should we include in the session?

Tags: php

This is a beginner question...

In a website, what type of data should or should not be included inside the session?  I understand that I should not include any info that needs to remain secure.  I'm more interested in programming best practice.  For example, it is possible to include into the session some data which would otherwise be sent from page to page as dependency injection.  Wouldn't that correspond to creating a global variable?

Generally speaking, what kind of data has or hasn't its place inside a session table?

Thanks,

JDelage

Comment: Don't you see that your question is too broad to have "best practice" answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should treat your session as a write-once, read many storage. But one which is rather volatile - e.g. the state of your underlying application data should be consistent (or recoverable) if all the sessions suddenly disappeared.

There are some exceptions to this (normally the shopping basket would be stored in the session - but you might want to perform stock adjustments to 'reserve' items prior to checkout). Here items may be added/edited/changed multiple times - so its not really write-once - but by pre-reserving stock items you are maintaining the recoverabiltiy of the database - but an implication of this is that you should reverse the stock adjustments *when the session expires* in the absence of completion.

If you start trying to store information about the data relating to individual page turns, you're quickly going to get into problems when the user starts clicking on the forward/back buttons or opens a new window.

Answer (score 7):

The minimum amount of information needed to maintain needed state information between requests.

Comment: I usually place in a UID, Hashes for CSRF, Captcha values etc. +1

Comment: @RobertPitt - what is CSRF?  Thx

Comment: @JDelage Type CSRF into your favorite search engine

Answer (score 1):

In general you can put anything you like in a session. It's bad practice to put information in a session that has to be present to make your page run without (technical) errors.

I suggest to minimize the amount of data in your session as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

stuff you can save in the session so that you dont have to make another database query for info that isn't going to change. like their username, address, phone number, account balance, security permissions on your site, etc.

Answer (score 1):

(This is perhaps more than you're looking for, but might make for good additional information to add to the good answers already posted.)

Since you mention best practices, you may want to look into some projects/technologies which can be used to take the idea of session state a bit further.  One common pitfall with horizontally scaling web applications across multiple servers is maintaining session state between them.  (User A logs in to Server A which stores the user's session, but on the next request hits Server B which doesn't know about User A's session, etc.)

One of the things I always end up saying to myself and to colleagues is that session by itself isn't really the best place to store data, even if that data is highly transient in nature.  A web server is a request/response system, not a data store.  It's highly tuned to the former, but not always so great for the latter.

Thus, there are ways to externalize your application's session data (or any stateful data, which should really be kept to a design minimum in the RESTful stateless nature of the web) from your web server and to another system.  [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) is a very common tool for this.  There are also drop-in session replacements (or configurable session options for various frameworks/environments) which store session in a database like SQL or MySQL.

One idea I've been toying with lately is to store session data (well, any transient data where it's OK to lose it in a catastrophe) in a NoSQL database.  [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) are my current top choices for this, but there's no shortage of other options.  CouchDB has excellent horizontal scaling, MongoDB is ridiculously fast when run entirely in-memory, etc.

One of the major benefits of something like this, at least for me, is that deployments can easily become non-events.  The web services on any given server can be re-started and the applications therein re-initialized without losing stateful data.  If the data is persisted to the disk (that is, not entirely run in-memory) then the server can even be rebooted without losing it.  Servers/services can drop in and out of the farm and users would never know the difference.

Additionally, externalizing this data allows you to analyze the data in potentially useful ways.  Query it, run metrics on it, interface with it via other web applications or entirely offline tools, etc.  It really opens up the options as a project grows in complexity.

(Again, this isn't really intended to answer your question, but rather to just add information that you may find useful.  It's something my colleagues and I have been tinkering with as of late and your question seemed like a good place to mention it.)

Comment: Re: session storage in NoSQL "when run entirely in-memory", why not just set the session storage path to a ramdisk? Don't throw a whole database server in the middle if you're only using it for that.