# How to save data to session

Tags: php, codeigniter

When the user clicks the "Select" link, I would like whatever is selected  to be saved to the session. Then another view will display all of the items stored in the session.
How can I do this? Or is there better solution or approach to use with this application?

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
foreach($query as $row){
  echo $row ->firstname; 
  echo $row ->lastname;
  echo "<a href=".base_url()."index.php/controller/function/$row->username /> Select </a>" 
}
?>
```

Comment: FYI: The wording of the original question was confusing. I modified it to clarify the question. If the new wording is not what you are asking, please just roll it back.

Comment: [Possible duplicate or related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4851324/1176000)

Answer (score 1):

This should be in your controller:

```
function my_function($username) {
    $users = json_decode($this->session->userdata('users'), true);
    $users[] = $username;
    $this->session->set_userdata('users', json_encode($users));
    print_r($this->session->userdata('users'));
}
```

Make sure [the session library is loaded](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). [Autoload](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html) suggested.

Comment: when i clicked more than one link will it save all to my session?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by all, but this one will save the username you send it to the session, so `/controller/my_function/pink` will save `'username'=>'pink'`... next time when you call it, it will overwrite it.

Comment: and also how can i output all selected to my view?

Comment: yes Shomz it was overwrite, but it should not be, it should add to the session everytime i click the select so i can display a list of username in view.

Comment: Assign `$this->session->all_userdata()` to a variable, and then print_r, foreach/echo or var_dump it in the view...

Comment: Then you can make it a JSON... so first you decode and read `json_decode($this->session->userdata('username'))`, then add a new username to it, and encode and overwrite the old version like it says in my answer.

Comment: can you teach me how? Sorry because I am new to codeigniter what is jason_decode?

Comment: See my updated answer. Basically, it's the code for all I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: It displays only one username, when i select another username it overwrite the previous slected

Comment: You're probably losing the session somewhere... possibly because you're not autoloading it.

Comment: But i already add the library session do you mean  autoloading it?

Comment: You either need to load it manually on every page, or use autoload, like I wrote in my answer. See the links.

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session'); this is in autoload.php does missing something?

Comment: Try this as the first line: `$users = json_decode($this->session->set_userdata('users'), true);`

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo all along - it works now. That's what happens when you're trying to help people at 6AM :D

Comment: No problem, glad you finally got it to work. Don't forget to mark the answer so that you don't start off with a bad answer rate.

Answer (score 0):

For example, on the top of your page:

```
<?PHP
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['yourvar']))
        echo $_SESSION['yourvar'];
    else
        $_SESSION['yourvar'] = 10;
?>
```